# if comparison from dictionary lists

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
```

and a function that takes the average of a list

```
def average(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)
```

I want the python function get_average(), to read through a dictionary. After that I want the function to take the average of a list in the dictionary and multiply the average of that list with a specific number (grading weights with .10 for homeworks,.30 for quizzes,or.60 for test) and give the total of the weighted homeworks, quizzes, and test. I am using a if statement to check whether the list selected from the for-loop in the dictionary is homework, quizzes, or tests.

```
def get_average(alice):
    hw=0
    qz=0
    ts=0

    for assignment in student:
        if assignment== ["homework"]:  
            hw=average(assignment)*.10
        if assignment==["quizzes"]:
            qz=average(assignment)*.30
        if assignment==["tests"]:
            ts=average(assignment)*.60

    return hw+qz+ts
```

This only returns zero. It should be 91.15

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are more than adequate. I just wanted to have a bit of fun trying something different.

With this method, you can easily extend the depth of marking criteria without the function's size expanding too much with all the extra `if` statements. It's also easier to edit, IMO, has less duplication going on and it's to the point.

```
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}

def average(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)

def get_average(student):
    criteria = {'homework': 0.10, 'quizzes': 0.30, 'tests': 0.60}
    return sum(y * average(student[x]) for (x,y) in criteria.iteritems())

alice['average'] = get_average(alice)

print alice
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the OP, while the others are simply showing how to solve your problem, this answer is truly much more pythonic and should be how you write python code.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through a dictionary gives you the keys in the dict. You need to use the values for your average function. You can also loop through both keys and values at the same time with [iteritems](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems):

This should work:

```
for assignment, scores in student.iteritems():
    if assignment=="homework":  
        hw=average(scores)*.10
    if assignment=="quizzes":
        qz=average(scores)*.30
    if assignment=="tests":
        ts=average(scores)*.60

return hw+qz+ts
```

You could also just loop through the dict and instead of scores have student[assignment], but that will require two lookups per loop iteration, so it's better to use iteritems.

Comment: I am new to python. When you type "for assignment, scores...." is scores being looped in the dictionary too?

Comment: In this case, and for future compatibility, it would be better to use `dict.items()` rather than `iteritems()`.

Comment: If he's using python3 yes, but for python2 iteritems will be less memory and time intensive... Granted for a 3 element dictionary like this it doesn't really matter, but as a matter of principle iteritems should be shown. Right?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code:

1. `assignment` iterates over keys of student i.e., `'name'`, `'homework'` etc. in `get_average()` function. So compare it with string `'homework'` not with list `['homework']`.
2. as I said `assignment` contains keys, so you need to call `average` with value of that key i.e., `student[assignment]`
3. You are iterating over `student` variable in `get_average()` function, so it should be `get_average(student)` rather than `get_average(alice)`.

Demo:

```
>>> def get_average(student):  
...     hw=0
...     qz=0
...     ts=0
...     for assignment in student:
...     # assignment iterates over keys of student i.e., 'name', 'homework' etc. So compare it with string 'homework' not with list ['homework']
...         if assignment== "homework":  
...         # as I said assignment contains keys, so you need to call average with value of that key i.e., student[assignment]
...             hw=average(student[assignment])*.10
...         if assignment=="quizzes":
...             qz=average(student[assignment])*.30
...         if assignment=="tests":
...             ts=average(student[assignment])*.60
...     return hw+qz+ts
... 
>>> def average(numbers):
...     return float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)
... 
>>> alice = {
...     "name": "Alice",
...     "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
...     "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
...     "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
... }
>>> get_average(alice)
91.14999999999999
```

Comment: Thanks this works too. I was using the dictionary format correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3, use `items()`, as `iteritems()` has been removed from this version:

```
def get_average(alice):

    tot = 0
    for tests, grades in alice.items():   #iterates over keys and values
        if tests == "homework":
            tot += average(grades)*0.1
        if tests == "quizzes":
            tot += average(grades)*0.3
        if tests == "tests":
            tot += average(grades)*0.6

    return tot
```

And yet another method using dict comprehension:

```
def get_average(alice):

    tot = 0
    gen = {test: average(grades) for test, grades in alice.items() if isinstance(grades, list)}
    for test, grades in gen.items():
        if test == "homework":
            tot += grades*0.1
        if test == "quizzes":
            tot += grades*0.3
        if test == "tests":
            tot += grades*0.6

    return tot
```